# Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

So I tried to use react-native on my brand new MacBook but I'm having some issues.

(I'm on MacOs BigSur Version 11.2.2 with a M1)

I followed the step on the environnement setup on react native website.

```
brew install node
brew install watchman
```

Installed Xcode and went to preferences > location > Command line tools > Xcode 12.4 (12D4e)

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then, I tried to do : npx react-native init tesr (I misspelled test and wrote tesr but I guess it's not really important).

and here I got this error :

```
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./tesr/ios && pod install".
```

So, I try `cd ./tesr/ios && pod install` and I see this :

````
    ### Command

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod install
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : macOS 11.2.2 (20D80)
       Xcode : 12.4 (12D4e)
         Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : 
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'tesr' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  target 'tesrTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:74:in `cdn_url?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:36:in `create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:21:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1073:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.
````

Even if there was an error, I wanted to try to run-ios, it obviously didn't worked, and then I went on some other stackOverflow page that got the same problem than me and couldn't solve my problem.

I'm new to macOS and apple product so I'm probably really bad at this but yeah if you have something that can help, I'll try it.

Comment: I think this is what you are probably running into: https://betterprogramming.pub/ruby-on-apple-silicon-m1-macs-fb159849b2f5 tldr; an issue with a particular ruby library (`ffi`) on Arm Macs when using the system version of ruby. It looks like the easiest way out is to use a custom version of Ruby. In case you are unaware, this is something that professional devs do a lot (the system Ruby on Macs is often out of date), so there are several easily configurable solutions out there, notably https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv and https://rvm.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it work, you just need to install Rosetta !
Here is a little bit of help : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861

Answer (score 3):

You may also add the following configuration in the .zshrc file:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

NOTE: Restart you mac after you add this configuration.

After Restarting, Just use your terminal to run these commands.

```
1) brew install libffi

2) brew install cocoapods
```

Then it is done.

If you face any error around null safety, you can run the following command in the terminal to launch you app.

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

This has solved my issue and is working fine. Hope it helps